# Using of word "just" with present perfect- "your friends have arrived" Vs "you friends have just arrived."

Tags: present-perfect

Could any one please explain the use of word " just " with present perfect ? I know that it's used to say that an action happened very recently, but I want to know what is the difference between placing and removing ***just*** from the sentence?

I think if want to remove it,  there must be a clear present relevance is that right ?

For example:

> your friends have arrived.

or

> you friends have just arrived.

Answer (score 1):

> Your friends have arrived.

This simply indicates that your friends arrived at some point in the past. They could have arrived earlier in the week.

> Your friends have just arrived.

This indicates that your friends have recently (just) arrived; probably in the last hour.

Comment: So, if i want to use the first one there should be a present relevance indicates that he is still here or something like that .. or both of the two forms should have a present relevance ?

Comment: For clarity, and to anticipate a follow-up quesion, yes. *Your friends have arrived, and they have already gone on ahead. Your friends have arrived, and are waiting in the back yard. Your friends have just arrived, and have gone to settle in.*

Comment: We often use present perfect with " just " because anything that just happened definitely will have a present relevance. Is that right ?

Comment: Anything that *just* happened has happened in the recent past. What the definition of *recent* is will depend on context. Are we talking travel plans, or continental drift?

Comment: I mean if I want to say that something just happened I will uses present perfect cause it has a present relevance or because it has just happened ?